# Error installing gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi

Tags: apt, arm, gdb

I get an error when I try to install the `gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi` package.
This is the error that I obtain when I run `apt-get install gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi`:

```
$ env LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gdb-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1848 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3887 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 246473 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi (from .../gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi_7.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi_7.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gdb/syscalls/sparc-linux.xml', which is also in package gdb 7.4.1+dfsg-0.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi_7.2-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there are some files which are provided by two packages.

What you can do is to remove the package you already have, in order to avoid the conflict.

In your case as a workaround you can try removing gdb (if you don't actually need it), then apt should allow you to install the gdb-arm-linux-gnueabi package that you were trying to install.

For the long term you should submit a bug to your distribution's bugtracker so the packagers come up with a proper fix.

---

It looks like you have two options:

1. recompile either of the two packages and remove the file from the control file.
2. try to download the deb file from the archive and use the --force-overwrite flag when installing it from the command line with dpkg. The question is knowing which version of the conflicting file you actually need, but in your case it seems to be a SPARC-related file which I think you could just ignore. I would go for option 2 which is much easier and faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need gdb for amd64. Is there any way to install the arm version without remove gdb-amd64?

Comment: It looks like you have two options: 1) recompile either of the two packages and remove the file from the control file and 2) try to download the deb file from the archive and use the --force-overwrite flag when installing it from the command line with dpkg. The question is knowing which version of the conflicting file you actually need, but in your case it seems to be a SPARC-related file which I think you could just ignore. I would go for option 2 which is much easier and faster.

Comment: Yeahh, your second option works!! Thank you very much, Cristian.